# Concurrent routines in Google's Go Language

Tags: go, concurrent-programming

Is it possible in go:
Suppose, I have 3 concurrent routines which can send integers to each other. Now, suppose both concurrent routine 2 & 3 sends an integer to concurrent routine 1. Is it possible in go that routine 1 takes both two values and process it farther ? To make it clear, I have following code:

```
package main
import "rand"

func Routine1(command12 chan int, response12 chan int, command13 chan int, response13 chan int ) {
for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
    i := rand.Intn(100)
if i%2 == 0 {
command12 <- i 
}

if i%2 != 0 {
command13 <- i 
}

print(<-response13, " 1st\n");
}
close(command12)
}

func Routine2(command12 chan int, response12 chan int, command23 chan int, response23 chan int) {
for i := 0; ; i++ {
    x, open := <-command12
    if !open {
        return;
    }
     print(x , " 2nd\n");
    y := rand.Intn(100)
    if i%2 == 0 {
command12 <- y 
}

if i%2 != 0 {
command23 <- y 
}
}
}

func Routine3(command13 chan int, response13 chan int, command23 chan int, response23 chan int) {
for i := 0; ; i++ {
    x, open := <-command13
    if !open {
        return;
    }
     print(x , " 3nd\n");
    y := rand.Intn(100)
    response23 <- y
}
}

func main() {
   command12 := make(chan int)
   response12 := make(chan int)
   command13 := make(chan int)
   response13 := make(chan int)
   command23 := make(chan int)
   response23 := make(chan int)

   go Routine1(command12, response12,command13, response13 )
   Routine2(command12, response12,command23, response23)
   Routine3(command13, response13,command23, response23 )
}
```

Here, in this example routine 1 can send an int to routine 2 or 3. I assume it is routine 3. Now suppose, routine 3 also send an int to routine 2. Is it possible for routine 2 to take those two values and process further (dynamic concurrent routines)? Can any body help to modify this program accordingly.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Concurrent routines in Go](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8232422/concurrent-routines-in-go)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hate abstract examples, anyway I will do my best to answer your question.

> Is it possible in go that routine 1 takes both two values and process it farther?

What do you want to archive? Inside routine1 you can either do:

```
// Read exactly one command from routine2 as well as exactly
// one command from routine3
cmd1 := <-command12
cmd2 := <-command13
// Process the pair of the two commands here
```

OR

```
// Process a single command only, which was either sent by routine2
// or by routine3. If there are commands available on both channels
// (command12 and command13) the select statement chooses a branch
// fairly.
select {
    case cmd1 := <-command12:
        // process command from routine 2
    case cmd2 := <-command13
        // process command from routine 3
}
```

I hope that will answer your question. Also note that Go channels support multiple-writers (as well as mutliple readers) by default. So, it might be enough to use exactly one input channel per goroutine. For example, routine1 might only read commands from a channel called command1, but both routine2 and routine3 might use the same command1 channel to send messages to routine1.

Another common idiom in Go is to pass a reply channel as part of the message. For example:

```
type Command struct {
    Cmd string
    Reply chan-> int
}

func routine2() {
    reply := make(chan int)
    command1 <- Command{"doSomething", reply}
    status := <-reply
}

func routine1() {
    cmd <- command1;
    // process cmd.Cmd
    cmd.Reply <- 200 // SUCCESS (status code)
}
```

Depending on your actual problem, this might simplify your program drastically :)

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible in GO, I mean creating concurrent channels.

Comment: Can you kindly help me, why it is not possible for concurrent routines ?